# Add multiple numbers from one text box to an array at one time

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox

I'm trying to take multiple numbers from a text box ex: 12 56 35, and add those numbers to an array at one time.

I tried to take the text from the text box and parse it into an int then add it to the array but it just doesn't work. It will work if I jut have one number in the text box but once I add multiple it doesn't work.

```
namespace Time4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int[] numbers = new int[10];
        int num = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
            {
                if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out numbers[i]))
                {
                    num = numbers[i];
                    richTextBox1.Text += num * 4 + "\n";
                    break;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: works with a singular number]

[image: Doesn't work with multiple numbers]

Comment: Have a look at the [`String.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-7.0) method and see if that will work for your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
        var input = "12 23 34";
        string[] stringNumbers = input.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (var str in stringNumbers)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(str, out int parsedInput))
            {
                // Add them to your array
            }
        }
```

Here you split the input string by the spaces, but you could also change this to a comma and replace `' '` with `','`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more versatility with which characters might be present between the numbers you want, you could use a *regular expression* to [split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split) the data, perhaps something like this:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var q = "12 34   67 A \t54 1e4 -99\r\n+87";
var nn = new List<int>();
var re = new Regex(@"\s+");

int n = 0;

foreach (string _ in re.Split(q).Where(s => int.TryParse(s, out n))) {
    nn.Add(n);
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", nn));
```

Outputs:

```
12, 34, 67, 54, -99, 87
```

The `_` in the `foreach` tells it that you don't care about the actual strings generated—the numbers will be transferred through the variable `n`.

If it's important that there are 10 integers found, you could add a check for `nn.Count == 10` after the loop.